# Can a static array be created using an int variable in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have a class as follows :

```
class A
{    //private members here
public:
   // other public functions here
template<typename T>
void create(int& no) const  // this function creates a static array containing no number of 
                            // elements of type T
{
  T vars[no]; // first, int no is a variable, can i create a static array here using a variable?
              /* second, I also see that visual studio is telling me "Local variable is not 
               initialized, does it need to be initialized? i only intend to use it for primitive  
               types and std::string but say if i needed to use if for a class object does it need 
               to be initialized? */
} 

};
```

I know that `int` variables cannot be used to create static arrays like so:

```
int num=10;
int arr[var];  // error, cannot use a variable to create a static array, it has to be const int
```

Because the variable has to be `const int`.

But I've seen code in books where they write code like in `create` function where they use an `int` variable to create static arrays of type `T`. Is this even legal?

Also, why is the visual studio telling me `Local variable is not initialized` at the declaration of the array?

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) are a common compiler extension, they are not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Also when I try [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/GT9M863KM) myself, I get errors but _not_ a "local variable is not initialized" error. Maybe that error is being caused by some of the code that you've commented out?

Comment: @NathanPierson None of this helps. I've read the reference you gave but not helpful. Can you open the question again please?

Comment: I don't understand what questions you have that weren't answered by the duplicate. It answers why "code like in `create`" will sometimes work. Your second, unrelated question about uninitialized variables is unanswerable without more information.

Comment: I don't think the `local variable is not initialized` is an error or a warning but three dots appear under the `vars` in `T vars[no];` line. I think it's more of a suggestion where visual studio is suggesting I write the code like so `T vars[no]{};` and then the dots dissapear. Can you comment why is that so? And also what would be the standard way to create a static array out of `int& no`? I'd appreciate it much!

Comment: There is no standard way to create a static array out of an `int&`. You can create a static array from a constant expression, or you can create a dynamic array from a non-constant expression. You can also use a standard library container like `std::vector` instead of trying to do it yourself. Depending on what you actually want `A` to be and what you want `create` to do, different approaches may be possible.

Comment: I will say that just from what's shown, the signature alone is a bit suspect. `create` is `const`, meaning it doesn't modify the `A` instance it's being called from. But it's also `void`, so it doesn't return anything. So what, exactly, do you expect to be able to _do_ with the array you're creating?

Comment: I'm trying to write a template function that creates no number of variables of variable types to use them later.

Comment: Basically assign different values later on to variables of `T vars[no]];` later.

Comment: If "later" means "after `create` has returned", your design is fundamentally flawed. `vars` ceases to exist when `create` returns. If your function doesn't store it somewhere else, and you don't return it so someone else can decide where to store it, you're out of luck. But this is turning into a discussion of very fundamental C++ issues like what is variable lifetime, which is beyond the scope of SO's question-and-answer format.

Comment: I have taken those issues you mentioned already into consideration. But thanks anyway!